# AS3 to C++ conversion – possible?

Tags: c++, xcode, ipad, actionscript, haxe

I built an iPad app in actionscript. A potential partner wants to pull my app into their app. They built their app natively using XCode. From what I understand, if my app had been built natively, I could simply export the code as a static library (.a file) for use by their app. Alas, I built mine in actionscript. So...

1. Is there a way to convert ActionScript 3 to C++?
2. Is one possible solution to do this conversion via AS3 to Haxe to C++?
3. Am I simply SOL and need to rebuild the game using XCode?

Thanks in advance.

Jason

Comment: Is a dependency on the Flash player acceptable for your potential partner's application? If it is you can embed the flash player and not have to do any porting.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. Thanks though.

Comment: #2 is potentially viable.  I wonder if you could investigate nabbing the AOT-compiled output of the air packager.  Finally - how tight does the integration have to be - can you invoke your app from his?

Comment: Hey Jeff. Thank you for your thoughts. I'll be honest, I was thinking about #2 from the highest level. I have no idea how to nab the AOT-compiled output from AIR but I will investigate. Yes, there will be a button within his app that will launch my app. Any additional thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider the Tamarin project or Tamarin redux. 
http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/tamarin/
It can be compiled in XCode as well. However, if your application is heavily depended on Flash runtime you have to implement all classes by yourself, because AVM contains only the basic AS3 classes.